# Display Most Popular Tags?

Tags: wordpress

I got the "Most Popular Tags" wordpress plugins so I can display the tags on my site, but it displays a bunch of general tags.  Is there any code I can add that will allow me to display the most popular tags on my site with the option of excluding the tags I don't want? Or a plugin that allows this?

Comment: Can't you just configure it through the Widgets menu in WP?

Comment: @BenM Do you mean the plugin or without the plugin?

Answer (score 2):

The solutions I see involve writing custom queries or plugins. While you asked about a specific plugin, know that this can be done through pure WP. Here are two options:

First, you can create a tag cloud using [`wp_tag_cloud`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud) and sort it by `count`, as such:

```
$tags = wp_tag_cloud(array(
    'echo' => false,
    'orderby' => 'count',
    'order' => 'DESC'
));
```

You can exclude certain tags from using the `exclude` parameter. You can also customize the font size output, or simply use CSS to ignore the tag cloud font sizes.

Another option is to use [`get_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/), which can be used as such:

```
$tags = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
    'orderby' => 'count',
    'order' => 'DESC',
));
```

I personally am a fan of the second, `get_terms` option. Like with `wp_tag_cloud`, you can pass a list of ids to exclude through the `exclude` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This code will return the most used tags on the last 30 days. With a little bit of jQuery and CSS you can customize to, for example, put a large font-size on the first one and a small font-size on the last one.

```
<ul id="footer-tags">
    <?php $wpdb->show_errors(); ?> 
    <?php
        global $wpdb;
        $term_ids = $wpdb->get_col("
            SELECT term_id FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy
            INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=$wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
            INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
            WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= $wpdb->posts.post_date");

if(count($term_ids) > 0){

  $tags = get_tags(array(
    'orderby' => 'count',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    'number'  => 28,
    'include' => $term_ids,
  ));

foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link ($tag->term_id) . '" rel="tag">' . $tag->name . '</a></li>';
}
}
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the get_tags->count does not really count the tags in a range. I have implemented this solution, please let me know if this works for you:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$term_ids = $wpdb->get_col("
SELECT term_id , count(*) cont FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=$wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= $wpdb->posts.post_date AND  $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy='post_tag'
GROUP BY term_id
ORDER BY cont DESC
LIMIT 5");

if(count($term_ids) > 0){
   $tags = get_tags(array(
   'orderby' => 'count',
   'order'   => 'DESC',
   'number'  => 5,
   'include' => $term_ids,
));
foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {
   echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link ($tag->term_id) . '" rel="tag">' . $tag->name . '</a></li>';
}
}
?>
```